# Android Emulator (API level 8) - just black screen after intro ANDROID message

Tags: android, android-emulator, nullpointerexception, ddms

I tried to start the emulator for API level 8, and it just shows a black screen after the ANDROID intro flashes.

I get the following error messages in the DDMS:

```
01-01 17:56:51.315: E/System(120): Failure starting core service
01-01 17:56:51.315: E/System(120): java.lang.NullPointerException

01-01 17:56:51.344: E/SystemServer(120): Failure starting DevicePolicyService
01-01 17:56:51.344: E/SystemServer(120): java.lang.NullPointerException

01-01 17:56:51.685: E/SystemServer(120): Failure starting StatusBarService
01-01 17:56:51.685: E/SystemServer(120): java.lang.NullPointerException

01-01 17:56:51.735: E/SystemServer(120): Failure starting Input Manager Service
01-01 17:56:51.735: E/SystemServer(120): java.lang.NullPointerException

01-01 17:56:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(120): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: ConnectivityThread
01-01 17:56:51.825: E/AndroidRuntime(120): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
[2012-01-01 17:52:39 - find_an_event] ------------------------------
[2012-01-01 17:52:39 - find_an_event] Android Launch!
[2012-01-01 17:52:39 - find_an_event] adb is running normally.
[2012-01-01 17:52:39 - find_an_event] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-01-01 17:52:39 - find_an_event] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2012-01-01 17:52:39 - find_an_event] Performing sync
[2012-01-01 17:52:39 - find_an_event] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'avd' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-01-01 17:52:39 - find_an_event] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avd'
[2012-01-01 17:53:02 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
[2012-01-01 17:53:02 - find_an_event] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-01-01 17:53:02 - find_an_event] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-01-01 18:11:31 - find_an_event] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'sync'!
```

I think the reason for this could be a failure to sync additional jar files that I have added to the path of my source files (signpost for oAuth). Any ideas on how I can get the emulator to work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means you have to close your already running Emulator, or really remove that emulator and create a new one. I don't know which tool do you use but maybe this link helps you:
[Help](http://www.helloandroid.com/content/eclipse-android-sdk-bugs-and-workarounds-common-mistakes)